# SharePoint 2013 : Get-PnPFile: No digest found!

Tags: 2013, document-library, error, pnp-powershell, pnp

How to download **SharePoint 2013** document library files using the PnP command **Get-PnPFile** ?

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url http://sharepoint2013site -TransformationOnPrem -CurrentCredential   
$items = (Get-PnPListItem -List "Documents" -Fields "Title","GUID","FileLeafRef").FieldValues
Get-PnPFile -Url $items[0].FileRef -FileName $items[0].FileLeafRef -Path C:\tmp -AsFile
```

The terminal returns the following error:

> Get-PnPFile: No digest found!

What I've already tried :

- Add the option **-ReturnConnection** to Connect-PnPOnline command and then adding the **-Connection** option to the Get-PnPFile command. I got the same result.
- Using the **-Force** option with the Get-PnPFile command. Same result.

I am using PowerShell Version: 7.3.3

Answer (score 1):

PnP PowerShell is officially not supported for being used in an on-premises context.

As per the PnP PowerShell documentation:

> `Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://portal.contoso.com" -TransformationOnPrem -CurrentCredential`
>
> Connects to on-premises SharePoint 2013, 2016 or 2019 site with the current user's on-premises Windows credential (e.g. domain\user). ***This option is only supported for being able to transform on-premises classic wiki, webpart, blog and publishing pages into modern pages in a SharePoint Online site.*** Although other PnP cmdlets might work as well, they're officially not supported for being used in an on-premises context. See http://aka.ms/sharepoint/modernization/pages for more details on page transformation.

**Source**: [Connect-PnPOnline - Example 11](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Connect-PnPOnline.html#example-11)